# How to install bxSlider

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I have 10+ years professional experience of php programming. But zero experience of jQuery and visual effects such as bxSlider. I wanted to try this effect, so I did the following, on an Amazon AWS EC2 standard Linux server + LAMP:

I created a new folder /var/www/html/test/ (when the default HTML root is /var/www/html). Everything else below is done inside /var/www/html/test/:

I created a subfolder pics, with some sample pictures:

```
pics/pic1.jpg
pics/pic2.jpg
pics/pic3.jpg
pics/pic4.jpg
```

Then I created this index.php:

```
<?php
echo '<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="bxslider">
<li><img src="pics/pic1.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="pics/pic2.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="pics/pic3.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="pics/pic4.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>';
?>
```

When tested with browser, I get the four sample pictures under each other, with the bullets of Unordered List.

Then I tried to install bxSlider, with the "instructions" found on the front page of their website bxslider.com.

Step 1: Link required files

I am instructed to "download the package from this site", and then link the stuff with this code:

```
<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

These links starting with "/" don't look compatible with my setting (my test folder is a subfolder of the default document root), so I remove the slashes, and I add this code inside the HEAD tags of my index.php:

```
<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

At this point I test my page, and it looks as it did afore. At least nothing got broken yet, so we continue.

I inspect the bxSlider zip file, which I get by clicking the download link at top right corner of their front page. Its folder structure does not match the given instructions. I foresee trouble brewing, and trouble I will get. The zip file contains these files and folders:

```
images/bx_loader.gif
images/controls.png
plugins/jquery.easing.1.3.js
plugins/jquery.fitvids.js
bower.json
jquery.bxslider.css
jquery.bxslider.js
jquery.bxslider.min.js
readme.md
```

But the instructed linking above, which I only modified by removing the slashes at start, assumes jquery.bxslider.css to be under folder lib, while jquery.bxslider.min.js should be under folder js. Ouuukay, and then what about the rest of the stuff? I take a look into my crystal ball, cross my fingers, and save the files on my server in these subfolders (inside /var/www/html/test/):

```
images/bx_loader.gif
images/controls.png
js/bower.json
js/jquery.bxslider.js
js/jquery.bxslider.min.js
js/readme.md
lib/jquery.bxslider.css
plugins/jquery.easing.1.3.js
plugins/jquery.fitvids.js
```

To double my odds of success, I also create these duplicate copies under a different path:

```
js/plugins/jquery.easing.1.3.js
js/plugins/jquery.fitvids.js
```

Now I have a... ahem... setup. Looks impressive, what can possibly go wrong? So I go to step 3 of the "instructions": Call the bxSlider. I am instructed to add this code... they don't mention where. Hmm, never mind, just add it. Somewhere.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
```

I try this code inside the BODY tags of HTML code, under the UL stuff. Result: HTTP 500 error.

Then I try this code inside the HEAD tags of HTML code, under the linking stuff. Result: HTTP 500 error.

Then I put script tags around this code, as it remains inside the head section of HTML code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
</script>
```

Result: HTTP 500 error.

Then I move the code above inside the BODY tags of HTML code, under the UL stuff. Result: HTTP 500 error.

Thanks for the instructions, guys. And now, could anyone give the actual instructions, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I found this video tutorial, which happens to include a full folder tree on the left. From there one can see that the plugins folder and other stuff are not really needed at all -- they are not included in the setup used by this tutorial. (I still don't know under which folder they should be, but never mind, if I don't need them now.)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l06E0Ia7I0I

I evolved my setting to be identical with the one presented in the video, and I still got HTTP 500 error. But wait, my stuff was in a PHP file, not in a plain HTML file, so I perfected the identicality of the setting, by making an HTML file. Now the slider functioned as expected.

Reason for the HTTP 500 error was unescaped quotation marks on this code line:

$('.slider').bxSlider();

I still think that more detailed instructions, and a downloadable demo of this same setting, would have been nice.

EDIT TO ADD:

Some further testing revealed that the two images included in this setting indeed are needed, bxSlider uses them as arrows, for example if we make this change to the settings:

`$(\'.slider\').bxSlider();`

=>

`$(\'.slider\').bxSlider({
      mode: \'fade\',
      captions: true
   });`

With this setting, everything functioned otherwise OK, but the arrows were missing. I knew where to click, where the arrows should have been, but the arrows were not there.

I copied the two image files to all possible folders, until finally the arrows became visible, when I copied the images here:

```
lib/images/bx_loader.gif
lib/images/controls.png
```

So even that YouTube video maker didn't know where to put the images, and he guessed, too. He guessed wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to setup bxSlider using a CDN. The only thing that you'd have to be concerned with is locating your images and your HTML (which looks like you have that already.) By using a CDN like [jsDelivr](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/), the script, stylesheet, and assets such as the 2 pngs are provided for you with low latency (**fast**).

[**Options**](http://bxslider.com/options)

**Snippet**

```html
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.css">
  <style>
    img {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="bxslider">
    <li>
      <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png" title="This is the Lena test image" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.ece.rice.edu/~wakin/images/lenaTest3.jpg" title="The captions are entered by using the 'title' attribute on the img element" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://image.slidesharecdn.com/random-110813050230-phpapp02/95/phdthesis-dr-shen-furao-30-728.jpg?cb=1313211855" title="This is the 3rd slide." />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_6ZIqLRChuQg/TF0-bhL6zoI/AAAAAAAAAoE/56OJXkRAFz4/s1600/lenaOriginal.png" title="This is the 4th slide" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var bx = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        /* Option values are quoted with the exception of numbers, true, and false.*/
        /* Each option ends with a comma (,) with the exception of the last one. */
        mode: 'vertical',
        captions: true,
        auto: true,
        autoHover: true
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```